# c# saving variable to csv issue

Tags: c#

I want to create a .csv file with some data that I find and copy from other files. I'm formatting csv with lines variable. Problem is that 5 and 6 value is skipped to next row. What am I doing wrong?

Cols names are fine, but there is something wrong later with the script, not really sure where and why.

```
col1         col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
filename      a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6
```

but instead I recive:

```
col1         col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
filename      a1   a2   a3    a4 
                   a5   a6
```

---

My code looks like this:

```
string getDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@getDir + "\\src");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); 
string str = "";
foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
  str = str + "," + file.Name;            
}

string lines="col1," + "col2," + "col3," + "col4 ," + "col5," + "col6," + "\n";

int ncheck = 1; 
int countFiles = d.GetFiles().Length; 

int vcheck = 0; 



    while (ncheck <= /*countFiles*/1) 
    {
        var getfile = str.Split(',')[ncheck];
        lines = lines + getfile;    
        while ( vcheck <= 4) 
        {
        string startSTR = "a1,a2,a3,a4,a5";
        var starts = startSTR.Split(',')[vcheck];

        string endSTR = "b1,b2,b3,b4,b5";
        var ends = endSTR.Split(',')[vcheck];


        string St = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(d + "\\" + getfile);

        int pFrom = St.IndexOf(starts) + starts.Length;
        if (St.IndexOf(starts) == -1 || St.IndexOf(ends) == -1) {pFrom=0;};
        int pTo = St.LastIndexOf(ends);
        if (St.IndexOf(starts) == -1 || St.IndexOf(ends) == -1) {pTo=pFrom+0;};




        String result = St.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
        if (St.IndexOf(starts) == -1 || St.IndexOf(ends) == -1) {result="Brak danych";};

        /*Console.WriteLine(starts);
        Console.WriteLine(result);          
        Console.WriteLine(ends);*/
        Console.WriteLine(lines);
        lines = lines + "," + result;
        Console.WriteLine(lines);
        vcheck++;
        }
        lines = lines + "\n";
        ncheck++;
        vcheck=0;
    }

System.IO.StreamWriter filetxt = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@getDir + "\\test.csv");
filetxt.WriteLine(lines);

filetxt.Close();
```

Comment: Have you verifed that none of the column sources contains `CR`, `LF` or `CRLF`?

Comment: Yes there is no CR, LF, CRLF

Comment: can you add one or more file(s) you're trying to merge to you post?

Comment: can't add those files :( that is why I changed cols names and strings that I'm searching for. This program is looking in x files for some string that is between startSTR and endSTR.

Comment: Then create some example files with columns matching the ones in your post. Somehow we need to reproduce your problem before we can try to solve it ;)

Comment: ok I found out that I have problems with website :) if there is string "www.somewebsite.com" then lines are breaking what that may be?

Comment: I don't know without some sample data...